# Centralizar Mapa com Multiplos marcadores

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Boa tarde pessoal!

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, mais precisarei utilizar a Geolocalização para pegar a localização do usuário, e mostrar os pontos próximos a ele, ate ai tudo bem, porem quando coloco um marcador em outro estado, ele da um zoom muito grande para pegar todos os marcadores, eu gostaria que ele ficasse centralizado e com um zoom de no máximo 15 da minha posição atual.
Sera que teria como.
Agradeço desde já

```js
var locations = [
    ['Estádio Mineirão', 'Av. Antônio Abrahão Caran, 1001 - São José, Belo Horizonte - MG, 31275-000, Brasil'],
    ['Estádio Independência', 'R. Pitangui, 3230 - Horto, Belo Horizonte - MG, 31110-732, Brasil', '#'],
    ['Estádio Maracanã', 'Av. Pres. Castelo Branco, s/n - Maracanã, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 20271-130, Brasil', '#'],
 ['Arena da Baixada', 'R. Buenos Aires, 1260 - Água Verde, Curitiba - PR, 80250-070, Brasil', '#']
];

var geocoder;
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng("-19.94370498", "-44.0317787"),
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {


        geocodeAddress(locations, i);
    }
  
}



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function geocodeAddress(locations, i) {
    var title = locations[i][0];
    var address = locations[i][1];
    var url = locations[i][2];
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': locations[i][1]
    },

    function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                icon: 'http://upcomunicacaovisual.com.br/modelos/imagem/up.png',
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: title,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                address: address,
                url: url
            })
            infoWindow(marker, map, title, address, url);
            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        } else {
            alert("geocode of " + address + " failed:" + status);
        }
    });
}

function infoWindow(marker, map, title, address, url) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        var html = "<div><h3>" + title + "</h3><p>" + address + "<br></div><a href='" + url + "'>Ver Perfil</a></p></div>";
        iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: html,
            maxWidth: 350
        });
        iw.open(map, marker);
    });
}

function createMarker(results) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: 'http://upcomunicacaovisual.com.br/modelos/imagem/up.png',
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        title: title,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        address: address,
        url: url
    })
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    infoWindow(marker, map, title, address, url);
    return marker;
}
```

```css
    html{ margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%}
    body{ margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%}   
 #map_canvas { height: 100%;  width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<script src="teste.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" ></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta é antiga, mas ainda pode ser útil para alguém.

Basta remover as referências dos *bounds*(que são os limites) no início:

```
//var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

E também dentro do *loop*, já que a variável não existe mais:

```
//bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
//map.fitBounds(bounds);
```